# Group by week days and Month

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I want to group data by week day and month. Say i want to find (sum of volume for all sundays in Januray) + (sum of volumes for all sundays in Feb) + ... What i did is like

```
  select CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),date,111),
         DATENAME(weekday,date) as Weekday,
         DATEPART(month,date) as Month,
         DATEPART(year,date) as year,
         sum(volume)
    from traffic_data_replica
group by CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),date,111),
         DATENAME(weekday,date),
         DATEPART(month,date),
         DATEPART(year,date)
order by DATEPART(year,date),
         CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),date,111),
         DATEPART(month,date),
         DATENAME(weekday,date) ;
```

But this is not the desired result i want :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are including the actual date in the group by (the `CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),date,111)`), so the day is the level of aggregation.  Try something like this:

```
SELECT Year(date), 
       Month(date), 
       Datename(weekday, date) AS Weekday, 
       Sum(volume) 
FROM   traffic_data_replica 
GROUP  BY Year(date), 
          Month(date), 
          Datename(weekday, date) 
ORDER  BY Year(date), 
          Month(date), 
          Datename(weekday, date);
```

You can use `datepart()` instead of `year()` and `month()`.  I just find the latter easier to read and type.

Comment: No what i need is sum of volumes for all sundays in month Januray..then sundays in Feb  and so on...what you have given above is the same result i got...

Comment: @bibinmatthew . . . This query should return one row per weekday per month, along with the sum of the volumes.  Your query returns one row per day, with the volumes summed for the day.  The queries should not be returning the same things.  If you set up a SQL Fiddle example, we can compare the result sets from the two queries.

Comment: Well explained :) Thanks bro @gordon